# Creating notebook failed jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to open new notebook (python 3) in Jupyter but it's showing the message that Creating notebook failed and only error in message.

Here is the image showing error.

[image: Image showing error]

Comment: Yeah definitely looking like error

Comment: Has this ever worked for you?